# Time or distance subway surfers

Tags: subway-surfers

Does subway surfers speed increase with an increase in distance or does it consistently increase over a period of time?

Answer (score 1):

The speed gets faster the further you go in the subway. You can't go the distance without the time; the longer you go, the farther you will go, the faster you will go.

As far as I can tell, you start at the same speed every time you start a run, if that's what you mean by 'increasing over time'.

Comment: That's not true.  if d(istance) = t(ime)*s(peed), then yes, the more time the more distance, **only and only if** speed is constant. Which may not be the case at all times

Comment: Technically "The more time the more distance" is true if and only if speed is greater than zero. What you are thinking of is that time and distance are not linearly related so an equal increase in time does not always mean the same increase in distance. I believe the question is assuming that speed is either a linear function of time or a linear function of distance and asking which one it is.

Comment: Or to put it another way if your speed is twice as much as your initial speed after one minute would it be three times as much after the second minutes, four times as much after the third minute, etc. Or else if your speed is twice as much as initial after 1000 metres would it be three times after 2000m, four times after 3000m, etc. The two are obviously not the same.

Comment: The question may also be asking about whether the increases are discrete (ie a step up at certain intervals, whether they are time or distance) or whether it is continuous (ie the speed is constantly increasing by a small amount).

Comment: Fairly sure it's continuous, @Chris.

Comment: @Mithrandir: I have no idea about the actual correct answer (though any of these games I've played have been continuous). The continuous or discrete thing was just an afterthought based on the phrasing "consistently increase over a period of time". My comments come from being a mathematician and therefore thinking far more than is healthy about functions. ;-)